# How to install phalcon framwork?

Tags: php, phalcon

It is the first time to use phalcon framwork .I followed the tutorials on the internet to install and It was easy but It fails and I can't run phalcon framework.

Can anybody help me?

my php version is v 7.4.25

**Another question:**

what is the difference in phalcon versions (ts-nts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Windows 10, to install Phalcon 4.1.2, you must:

1. Download and install XAMPP version [7.4.29](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html);
2. Download and install the extension [Php-PSR 1.0.0 TS](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/psr/1.0.0/php_psr-1.0.0-7.4-ts-vc15-x64.zip) (XAMPP uses TS [Thread Safe]);
3. Download and install [Phalcon 4.1.2 TS](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/releases/download/v4.1.2/phalcon_x64_vc15_php7.4_4.1.2+5275.zip).

You can find the full instructions [here](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/webserver-setup#xampp). In Windows you do not need to compile anything.

Comment: Can you recommend any course for it? please.

Comment: Sure, you can go through the Phalcon tutorials in the documentation: https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/tutorial-basic#tutorial---basic. Also, this is an excellent book: https://www.packtpub.com/product/phalcon-cookbook/9781784396886  although it is for Phalcon 3.4 the introduction is valid for 4.0 and 5.0. Just keep in mind when you go through the code that it must be upgraded to 4.0+

Answer (score 0):

The last stable release of Phalcon is version 4.1.2 and it supports up to PHP 7.4, but does not support PHP 8.  The Phalcon dev team are working on Phalcon 5.0 and that release, which will support PHP8, which is currently available as a "release candidate".  They hope to have the final release out in a few weeks.

In order to get the version 4.1.2 of Phalcon installed on our Ubuntu Linux (20.04 and 22.04) server, we had to compile from source.

You can find the commands compile from source for Linux servers here:

https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/installation#compilation

Comment: My OS is windows 10 . I want learning phalcon on my device.